# Compiling chef cookbooks without executing

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

how to compile chef cookbooks without actually executing in chef Zero mode?

When chef client is executed it first compiles and then executes but my question is that is there anyway chef cookbooks can be only just compiled in Chef local mode?

Comment: Do you mean why run mode?

Answer (score 1):

This is, in general, not a thing. What we call "compile phase" is not like a C or Java compiler where there is an actual output of some kind. It's just moving from the on-disk recipe code files to an in-memory object representation. The name is a bit misleading, but such is the way of things when names were picked long ago.